# What is the purpose of filtering a log file using this Perl one-liner before displaying it in the terminal?

Tags: perl

I came across this script which was not written by me, but because of an issue I need to know what it does.

What is the purpose of filtering the log file using this Perl one-liner?

```
 cat log.txt | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)/ /g'
```

The `log.txt` file contains the output of a series of commands. I do not understand what is being filtered here, and why it might be useful.

Comment: What part don't you understand?  What is the behavior when you actually run it?

Comment: Whoever is editing this question, you can't just put backticks around the script and not fix the character escaping or it DRASTICALLY changes the behavior of the code in question

Comment: perl -pe 's/\e([^[]]|[.?[a-zA-Z]|].?\a)/ /g' , It would be great if you would tell me what " perl -pe " does ...??? Apparently I not able figure what changes it does to the log.txt file. Because there are no visible changes ...

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Comment: `perl -pe` makes perl run like `sed`. It iterates a line at a time, runs the code block and then prints the current line. Normally that means a transform is applied to `$_` - the current line (which `s///` does)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the code should remove [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) from the input, i.e codes to set colors, window title .... Since some of these code might cause harm it might be a security measure  in case some kind of attack was able to include such escape codes into the log file. Since usually a log file does not contain any such escape codes this would also explain why you don't see any effect of this statement for normal log files.

For more information about this kind of attack see [A Blast From the Past: Executing Code in Terminal Emulators via Escape Sequences](https://www.proteansec.com/linux/blast-past-executing-code-terminal-emulators-via-escape-sequences/).

BTW, while your question looks bad on the first view it is actually not. But you might try to improve questions by at least formatting it properly. Otherwise you risk that this questions gets down-voted fast.

Answer (score 1):

First, the command line suffers from a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). `perl` is fully capable of reading from a file name on the command line.

So,

```
$ perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)/ /g' log.txt
```

would have done the same thing, but avoided spawning an extra process.

Now, `-e` is followed by a script for `perl` to execute. In this case, we have a single global substitution.

`\e` in a [Perl regex pattern](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlreref) corresponds to the escape character, `x1b`.

The pattern following `\e` looks like the author wants to match [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

The [`-p` option](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlrun) essentially wraps the script specified with `-e` in `while` loop, so the `s///` is executed for each line of the input.

The pattern probably does the job for this simple purpose, but one might benefit from using [Regexp::Common::ANSIescape](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::ANSIescape) as in:

`$ perl -MRegexp::Common::ANSIescape=ANSIescape,no_defaults -pe 's/$RE{ANSIescape}/ /g' log.txt`

Of course, if one uses a script like this very often, one might want to either use an alias, or even write a very short script that does this, as in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use Regexp::Common 'ANSIescape', 'no_defaults';

while (<>) {
    s/$RE{ANSIescape}/ /g;
    print;
}
```